# Facebook Webhook Event Trigger

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have successfully added the callback URL in the Messenger webhook settings page and used the ColdFusion server to receive token verification and message events.
Token verification works fine on the callback URL but the event is not triggering when sending a message via Facebook messenger. When testing the same pattern of events with POSTMAN the server-side code runs perfectly fine.

Did anyone know about this issue? ColdFusion server is equally receiving POST and GET requests properly.

I am not facing any server-side code issue but don't know why the messages are triggering webhook URL